# Complex signals is the same as natural signal

Tags: signal, signal-processing

I am working using a sinuasidal signal along with the complex signal derived form it and when I plot the signals spectrum using FFT I got the same spectrum and it turns out that the signals are the same which I don't get?

````
import scipy
from scipy import fftpack
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter,filtfilt
from scipy.signal import freqz
import numpy as np
#from scipy.signal import butter,filtfilt# Filter requirements.
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    print()
    print("low is ",low)
    print("high is ",high)
    print()
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):  
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y
freqs = [7,20,30]
sins = ['sin', 'cos', 'sin']
amps = [1,0.5,0.2]
phases = [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/3]
def m_signal(t, freqs, sins, amps, phases):
  ops = np.zeros(t.shape)
  for f,s,a,p in zip(freqs, sins, amps, phases):
    if s == 'sin':
      ops += a*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*t + p)
    if s == 'cos':
      ops += a*np.cos(2*np.pi*f*t + p)
  return ops

fs = 240
T = 2
nsamples = fs*T
time = np.linspace(0, T, num=nsamples)
sig0 = m_signal(time, freqs, sins, amps, phases)  

def time_signal(n):
  return np.sin(2*np.pi*n*7) + np.cos(2*np.pi*n*30 - np.pi/4)

# Complex Signal
def signal(n):
  s1 = np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*n*7)/(2*1j) - np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*n*7)/(2*1j)
  s2 = 0.5*np.exp(1j*(2*np.pi*n*30 - np.pi/4)) + 0.5*np.exp(-1j*(2*np.pi*n*30 - np.pi/4))
  comp = s1 + s2
  return comp

# If fs is 240 Hz and T (time) is 2 sec, then the number of samples is fs*T
fs = 240
T = 2
nsamples = fs*T
time = np.linspace(0, T, num=nsamples)

time.shape

def plot_spectrum(nsamples, x, fs):
  Xf = fftpack.fft(x, nsamples)
  ff = np.linspace(0.0, fs/2, int(nsamples/2))
  # print(ff)
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,3))
  ax.plot(ff, 2.0/nsamples * np.abs(Xf[:nsamples//2]))
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.show()

sig = time_signal(time)
csig = signal(time)

sig.shape

# Signal on time domain
plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,3))
plt.clf()
plt.plot(time, sig, label='Signal')
plt.grid(True) 
plt.show()

sig

csig

# Complexified signal (Magnitude)
plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,3))
plt.clf()
plt.plot(time, np.abs(csig), label='Signal')
plt.grid(True) 
plt.show()


# Complexified signal (Phase)
plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,3))
plt.clf()
plt.plot(time, np.angle(csig), label='Signal')
plt.grid(True) 
plt.show()

# Spectrum of the signal sig
plot_spectrum(nsamples, sig, fs)

# Spectrum of the complexified signal csig
plot_spectrum(nsamples, csig, fs)

print(csig)
```
````

Comment: Please can you rephrase the question, it is not clear what you are asking. There is no context for the code listing?

Comment: Ask a question - it won't hurt.

Comment: Welome to EE.SE. It is not clear, if you want to solve a problem with the programming language you are using or if you lack some basic understanding of specific signal processing facts. Please enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You refer to a

> sinuasidal signal along with the complex signal derived form it

Using complex numbers to represent a sinusoid is simply a method of conveying magnitude, frequency, and phase. This is true whether we use the exponential notation or the cos(x) + j*sin(x) related by Euler's famous formula. The "j" multiplier is simply a phase shift of +pi/2. Your signal() and time_signal() functions are equivalent and therefore produce the same spectral result.

Answer (score 1):

Euler's formula tells us

$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + j\sin\theta.$$

We can rearrange this to get

$$\sin\theta=\frac{1}{2j}\left(e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}\right)$$
and
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{j\theta}+e^{-j\theta}\right).$$

Let's look at one component of your signal. In the time domain you have `np.sin(2*np.pi*n*7)`, or \$x(t)=\sin(2\pi n 7)\$.

Using the formula above we can write
$$\sin(2\pi n 7)=\frac{1}{2j}\left(e^{j2\pi n 7}-e^{-j2\pi n 7}\right),$$

which is exactly what is in your code for the complex signal:

> `s1 = np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*n*7)/(2*1j) - np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*n*7)/(2*1j)`

You'll find the other component (with frequency 30) are similarly related using the cosine formula.

So your "complex" signal was produced from the "time domain" signal (or possibly vice versa) by applying Euler's formula. They will have the exact same time domain waveform and frequency spectrum, because they are actually the same signal, just written in terms of different basis functions.